# Do we need admin priviledge to install NativeHost client of chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, registry

I am developing a chrome extension which communicates to a NativeHost client installed under NativeHost dorectory on Mac, but to install it on the Windows we need to change the registory values. Do we need admin privildge for that**?** if yes, then doe we have any way to bypass this**?**
because my users may/maynot have admin privildge to use my extension.

Comment: To add an regitry for current user like 
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json" /f     we dont  need any admin privildge. i just checked.

Answer (score 1):

As you can add native messaging hosts in the Current User key (HKCU/HKEY_CURRENT_USER) then you do not need admin privilege for that.
It would be installed only for that user.